# What should I do when I receive an error saying 'coroutine was never awaited' with asyncio.create_task?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I want to create a task with asyncio.create_task, which must run in the background **without blocking currently running function**. However, when I attempt to create it, I get an error, saying that coroutine was never awaited.

I tried to just call create_task() with a coroutine without awaiting it first, thinking that it would run after I created the task:

```py
async def _turn_end_timer(self):
    await asyncio.sleep(self.turn_time)
    self.next_turn()
def next_turn(self):
    if self._turn_worker is not None:
        self._turn_worker.cancel()
    if len(self.turn_queue) == 0:
        self.current_turn_username = None
        return
    self.current_turn_username = self.turn_queue.pop(0)
    coro = self._turn_end_timer()
    self._turn_worker = asyncio.create_task(coro)
    self.send_turn_queue_update()
```

That did not work. The event loop is running:

```py
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

What does that mean and how to fix it? I do not want to use `threading` module, since it would cause more trouble.

Comment: You should `await` it. It is really that simple.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg I don't want to await it, I want to create a task so it would be running in background

Comment: `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())` means "**call `main` now, wait for it to complete**, and then run **its result** in the event loop".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

asyncio would not allow multiple event_loop to run but if you need a by pass that is you are getting the event_loop already running then you can use this library

```
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
```

This will allow for a multi threaded behaviour